# flow of loading and errors state in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm building a simple search form which would show a loading screen after submitting a form and errors depending on the results of the fetch.

is there a standard pattern for triggering the loading and error states upon an action such as search / fetching from an api?

it seems overkill the way I'm doing it - if I had more reducers I'd have to replicate the same logic in each one to clear the loading state

```
class Search extends Component {
    onSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const { search } = this.props;
        search();
    }

    render() {
        const { error, loading } = this.props;
        return() {
            <>
                <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                    <input type="submit" value="search" />
                </form>
                {loading && <Loader />}
                {error && <p>{error}</p>}
            </>
        }
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    error: state.error,
    loading: state.loading
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {search})(Search);
```

userActions

```
export const doSearch = (url) => dispatch => {
    dispatch({
        type: LOADING
    })

    fetch(`${url}`)
    .then(response =>
        dispatch({
            type: RECEIVE_DATA,
            payload: response
        })
    )
    .catch(error => {
        dispatch({
            type: ERROR,
            payload: error
        })
    })
}
```

userReducers

```
const initialState = {
    error: '',
    loading: false,
    results: ''
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case LOADING:
            return {
                ...state,
                error: '',
                loading: true
            }

        case ERROR:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                error: action.payload.message
            }

        case RECEIVE_RESULTS:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                results: action.payload.items
            }

        default:
            return state;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As Rishabh said in his answer this is the standard way of doing it. It might seem quite a lot of code but it is worth it, as it is separation of concerns. There are some conventions you need to use. In general you don't dispatch({ type: LOADING }) but rather dispatch({ type: SEARCH_REQUEST }). As for the other two actions these should be types SEARCH_SUCCESS and SEARCH_FAILURE

Comment: This code that you have below your form:
{loading && <Loader />}
{error && <p>{error}</p>}
should move within the render and before return and write something like:
if (loading){
return <Loader/>
} and the same for the error. As you know, react component can have 1 return, so while it's loading it will be showing the Loader and then when the content is loaded it will render your form

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the way you have approached the problem is perfectly fine. This is the way we usually go about it by changing the value of loading in the redux store as and when it is needed. Though the naming convention that is often used is to call it 'isLoading' instead of 'loading'.
Are you finding any issues with your current implementation that you are looking for an answer to?